# How to properly convert results from a @Query of a repository?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to do this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from student, class where student.class = class.id ..(and more)", nativeQuery= true)
    List<MyObject> findByStudentId(@Param("studentId") long studentId);
```

This currently throws me an exception of a converter, something like this:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [com.project.model.MyObject]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:324) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

So I guess there must be a converted to implement.

When I return a List works perfectly but I return an Object with the field results as an array.

I was wondering what is the best way to make this conversion to keep using my query without have to modify everything?

Comment: Well, I think you could return a list of students. Then you can use directly the student objects, instead of create a custom object with a subset of fields.. Why do you want to use a custom object?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you have to create a custom interface to extract result from your query. Let's say your query returns student_id, class_id, student_name, student_class and so on. All you need is create an interface like below

```
  interface MyCustomObject{
        Long getStudentId();
        Long getClassId();      
        String getStudentName();
        String getStudentClass();            
    }
```

Then your query will be

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s.student_id, c.class_id, s.student_name, s.student_class from student s, class c where student.class = class.id ..(and more)", nativeQuery= true)
    List<MyCustomObject> findByStudentId(@Param("studentId") long studentId);
```

I would suggest to specify selected column names for this kind of custom query.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from student, class where student.class = class.id ..(and more)", nativeQuery= true)
    List<MyObject> findByStudentId(@Param("studentId") long studentId);
```

you can simply map it to object array :

```
**List<Object[]>** findByStudentId(@Param("studentId") long studentId);
```

in service layer , this can be mapped to the setter elements of MyObject as :

```
List<Object[]> listitems=repository.findByStudentId(long studentid);
for(Object obj:listitems){
MyObject myobj=new MyObject();
System.out.println(obj[1].toString());  myobj.setid(obj[1].toString());
System.out.println(obj[2].toString());

....
}
```